# set http headers get request for oxford api in angular 6

Tags: typescript, header, angular6

```
public autocomplete(w):any {  

  let options = {
    headers:{
      'Accept':  'application/json',
      'app_id': 'myid',
      "app_key": "mykey"
    } as any
  }

  this.word = w.toLowerCase() ;
  let myResponse = this._http.get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/search/en/translations=es?q='+this.word,options);
  return myResponse;

 }
```

I have tried all types of headers request to set oxford API headers for authentication but there is only getting result is :  403 forbidden !

## Please suggest me right way

Answer (score 0):

I did bit restructure of your code and created a header object and request options. It should work. Import the below http modules from angular

```
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

....... and your method should be like below. Update me if it's working for you or not.

```
  public autocomplete(w): any {
    const baseUrl =
      'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/search/en/translations=es?q=';
    w = w.toLowerCase();

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('app_id','myId');
    headers.append('app_key','myKey');

    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + w, options);
  }
```

Comment: There is an error : Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

Comment: can you please put the sample on stackblitz or plunkr ? Just want to look into why its throwing the error.